# Why does removing the ORDER BY significantly speed up this query?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization, sql-order-by

I have the following query (some of it is code-generated so pardon the poor formatting):

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(gi.start_time, '') start_time,
COALESCE(b.name, '') bank,
COALESCE(a.id, '') account_id,
COALESCE(a.account_number, '') account_number,
COALESCE(at.code, '') account_type,
COALESCE(a.open_date, '') open_date,
COALESCE(a.interest_rate, '') interest_rate,
COALESCE(a.maturity_date, '') maturity_date,
COALESCE(a.opening_balance, '') opening_balance,
COALESCE(a.has_e_statement, '') has_e_statement,
COALESCE(a.has_bill_pay, '') has_bill_pay,
COALESCE(a.has_overdraft_protection, '') has_overdraft_protection,
COALESCE(a.balance, '') balance,
COALESCE(a.business_or_personal, '') business_or_personal,
COALESCE(a.cumulative_balance, '') cumulative_balance,
COALESCE(c.customer_number, '') customer_number,
COALESCE(c.social_security_number, '') social_security_number,
COALESCE(c.name, '') customer_name,
COALESCE(c.phone, '') phone,
COALESCE(c.deceased, '') deceased,
COALESCE(c.do_not_mail, '') do_not_mail,
COALESCE(cdob.date_of_birth, '') date_of_birth,
COALESCE(ad.line1, '') line1,
COALESCE(ad.line2, '') line2,
COALESCE(ad.city, '') city,
COALESCE(s.name, '') state,
COALESCE(ad.zip, '') zip,
COALESCE(o.officer_number, '') officer_number,
COALESCE(o.name, '') officer_name,
COALESCE(po.line1, '') po_box,
COALESCE(po.city, '') po_city,
COALESCE(po_state.name, '') po_state,
COALESCE(po.zip, '') zip,
COALESCE(br.number, '') branch_number,
COALESCE(cd_type.code, '') cd_type,
COALESCE(mp.product_number, '') macatawa_product_number,
COALESCE(mp.product_name, '') macatawa_product_name,
COALESCE(pt.name, '') macatawa_product_type,
COALESCE(hhsc.name, '') harte_hanks_service_category,
COALESCE(mp.hoh_hierarchy, '') hoh_hierarchy,
COALESCE(cft.name, '') core_file_type,
COALESCE(oa.line1, '') original_address_line1,
COALESCE(oa.line2, '') original_address_line2,
COALESCE(uc.code, '') use_class
            FROM account a
            JOIN customer c ON a.customer_id = c.id
            JOIN officer o ON a.officer_id = o.id
            JOIN account_address aa ON aa.account_id = a.id
       LEFT JOIN account_po_box apb ON apb.account_id = a.id                
            JOIN address ad ON aa.address_id = ad.id
            JOIN original_address oa ON oa.address_id = ad.id
       LEFT JOIN address po ON apb.address_id = po.id
            JOIN state s ON s.id = ad.state_id
       LEFT JOIN state po_state ON po_state.id = po.state_id
       LEFT JOIN branch br ON a.branch_id = br.id
            JOIN account_import ai ON a.account_import_id = ai.id
            JOIN generic_import gi ON gi.id = ai.generic_import_id
            JOIN import_bundle ib ON gi.import_bundle_id = ib.id
            JOIN bank b ON b.id = ib.bank_id
       LEFT JOIN customer_date_of_birth cdob ON cdob.customer_id = c.id
       LEFT JOIN cd_type ON a.cd_type_id = cd_type.id
       LEFT JOIN account_macatawa_product amp ON amp.account_id = a.id
       LEFT JOIN macatawa_product mp ON mp.id = amp.macatawa_product_id
       LEFT JOIN product_type pt ON pt.id = mp.product_type_id
       LEFT JOIN harte_hanks_service_category hhsc ON hhsc.id = mp.harte_hanks_service_category_id
       LEFT JOIN core_file_type cft ON cft.id = mp.core_file_type_id
       LEFT JOIN use_class uc ON a.use_class_id = uc.id
       LEFT JOIN account_type at ON a.account_type_id = at.id

         WHERE 1
           AND gi.active = 1
           AND b.id = 8 AND ib.is_finished = 1
      ORDER BY a.id
         LIMIT 10
```

I have indexes on all the appropriate columns, including `account.id` AKA `a.id`. Despite this fact, my query significantly speeds up (it goes from 10 seconds to 0 seconds) if I remove the `ORDER BY`. Why is this?

Comment: sorting takes time?

Comment: ORDER BY is a necessary evil to ensure data order, otherwise there's no guarantee but likely will be based on insertion order.

Comment: I know sorting takes time but 10 seconds for my ~30,000-row result set seems like a lot. Maybe it's sorting before the `WHERE`.

Comment: The resulting set rarely has anything to do with how long it takes to run a query. The only thing that affects is I/O time. Query performance moreso depends on the size of the data you're querying as well as any aggregations you're applying. It's good that you have indexes but see Ned's answer below. Also, make sure your clustered index is on your id column as it increases monotonically.

Comment: I don't even want to know the cartesian product of that query :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because with the ORDER BY, it has to retrieve all the rows to sort them to get the first 10 by a.id.  Without the ORDER BY, it can simply retrieve the first 10 rows it finds and ignore the rest.

Also, be careful when profiling queries: the first can fill the cache with data, and subsequent queries go faster not because the SQL is different, but because it's pulling data from the cache instead of the disk.

Comment: I was wondering about this -- is there some sort of flag you can use to ensure the query results aren't coming from the cache?

Comment: @yc: It depends on the DBM but with MySQL I think you can use `RESET QUERY CACHE` before running the query. Note that you need the RELOAD privilege for this operation.

Comment: @bitxwise that will reset the cache for the whole DB, though, yes, and not just the querying user?

Comment: @yc: I guess that's sort of a shotgun approach...haha

Comment: @bitxwise We're obviously getting off topic, but what about adding non-effective conditionals? like, `OR 1=2`? Would that force it to query without the cache?

Comment: @yc: Yeah, a little straying but to address your q, I think query optimizers would typically process non-effective conditionals prior to any data scanning/seeking. So if a non-effective condition is deemed false, no scanning/seeking would take place. However, if it's true, then the optimizer would fall back on caching sets.